# how to remotely Debug Azure web app slot

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have used Azure remote debugging of my web apps very effectively. However, in prod, we are using deployment slots and our staging slot is causing some errors and needs to be debugged. Some of my team members tried to remotely debug it, but when they attached, it produced the following error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x89710023): Unable to
>   connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugger named
>   'mysite123prod-staging.azurewebsites.net'.  The connection with the
>   remote endpoint was terminated.
>
> at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Interop.Internal.IDebuggerInternal120.ConnectToServer(String
>   szServerName, VsDebugRemoteConnectOptions[] pConnectOptions,
>   CONNECT_REASON ConnectReason, Int32 fIncrementUsageCount,
>   IDebugCoreServer3& ppServer)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Azure.MicrosoftWeb.Operations.RemoteDiagnosticsSessionBase.ConnectToServer(String
>   site, String user, String password)

Can this be done in Azure and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

There could be many possible reasons for the issue.

- You might have turned off the firewall on your machine.
- Check that if the Remote Debugging on the Azure Web App is set to ON
  in the portal and has the correct Remote Visual Studio version.
- If this worked well before, you could delete the web app and
  re-publish it again. You may also want to open the below ports and
  check if that solves your issue.
  [image]

For more details, refer to [Configure the Windows Firewall for Remote Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/configure-the-windows-firewall-for-remote-debugging#ports-on-the-remote-computer-that-enable-remote-debugging) and [Remote Debugging Errors and Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-errors-and-troubleshooting).

Comment: Thanks for the response! Right now the slot is set to On and 2017 for debugging, which is correct. I can successfully debug the same app service in the test environment previously but without any slots on it, so I think that would rule out the ports and firewall issue on my end, right?